# Ghost CMS Heroku new theme added by git not displaying

Tags: heroku, ghost

I added a new theme to ghost cms, It displays in the listing on my local machine, but on my heroku instance I cant see it in the list of available themes.

Is there a way to restart Ghost in heroku, or a way of forcing it to appear? Ive tried restarting the dynos, and redeploying to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@chris I solved the issue, it turns out my content path in config.production.json was wrong. It wasnt looking in the right place for the themes

it was

```
 "paths": {
      "contentPath": "content/"
  },
```

and it needed to be

```
  "paths": {
      "contentPath": "content"
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

How did you install the theme? The [instructions](https://help.ghost.org/article/31-upload-themes) make it look like this involves dropping files into a directory (either using the admin UI or manually).

Heroku's [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) isn't compatible with that:

> Each dyno gets its own ephemeral filesystem, with a fresh copy of the most recently deployed code. During the dyno’s lifetime its running processes can use the filesystem as a temporary scratchpad, but no files that are written are visible to processes in any other dyno and any files written will be discarded the moment the dyno is stopped or restarted. For example, this occurs any time a dyno is replaced due to application deployment and approximately once a day as part of normal dyno management.

Any changes you make to the filesystem will be lost when the dyno restarts, which happens at least once per day. (Maybe counter-intuitively, restarting your dyno will have the opposite effect from what you want.)

You'll have to commit the theme files to your Git repository and deploy the new code to Heroku. In addition to making the change persist across dyno restarts, this also makes the new theme available to all dynos (if you scale beyond one).

Comment: Hey @chris, the theme is added to git, and its pushed up to heroku that way. I can see the theme folder is there on heroku, by running heroku run bash. Ghost is not picking up the folder changes

Comment: @GraemePaul, you see the new theme file beside `casper`? Is it a symlink or a real file? ([This starter pack](https://github.com/cobyism/ghost-on-heroku) uses a symlink for the default theme.)